# Ошибка приложения после создания установщика

Tags: c#, visual-studio, install, setup

Написал программу которая отлично работает в Visual Studio. Но при создании установщика и последующей установке, в приложении при нажатии на кнопку Настройки выползает окно такого типа с ошибкой.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный текст ошибки:
        Подробная информация об использовании оперативной 
    (JIT) отладки вместо данного диалогового 
    окна содержится в конце этого сообщения.

```
************** Текст исключения **************
System.NullReferenceException: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.
   в ProcMail.Settings..ctor() в C:\Users\DAVID\source\repos\ProcMail\ProcMail\ProgramSettings.cs:строка 23
   в ProcMail.MailDistributor.btnSettings_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в C:\Users\DAVID\source\repos\ProcMail\ProcMail\MailDistributor.cs:строка 50
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Button.PerformClick()
   в System.Windows.Forms.Form.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.ProcessDialogKey(Keys keyData)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessMessage(Message& msg)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Control.PreProcessControlMessageInternal(Control target, Message& msg)
   в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.PreTranslateMessage(MSG& msg)


************** Загруженные сборки **************
mscorlib
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
ProcMail
    Версия сборки: 1.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 1.0.0.0
    CodeBase: file:///D:/Proc/ProcMail.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Configuration
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Configuration/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Configuration.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Core
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Core/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Xml
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Xml/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Xml.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Data/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Data.resources
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Data.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089/System.Data.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Transactions
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.Transactions/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Transactions.dll
----------------------------------------
System.EnterpriseServices
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_32/System.EnterpriseServices/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.EnterpriseServices.dll
----------------------------------------
mscorlib.resources
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/mscorlib.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089/mscorlib.resources.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Runtime.Caching
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Runtime.Caching/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Runtime.Caching.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Numerics
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Numerics/v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Numerics.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms.resources
    Версия сборки: 4.0.0.0
    Версия Win32: 4.7.2558.0 built by: NET471REL1
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms.resources/v4.0_4.0.0.0_ru_b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.resources.dll
----------------------------------------

************** Оперативная отладка (JIT) **************
Для подключения оперативной (JIT) отладки файл .config данного
приложения или компьютера (machine.config) должен иметь
значение jitDebugging, установленное в секции system.windows.forms.
Приложение также должно быть скомпилировано с включенной
отладкой.

Например:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

При включенной отладке JIT любое необрабатываемое исключение
пересылается отладчику JIT, зарегистрированному на данном компьютере,
вместо того чтобы обрабатываться данным диалоговым окном.
```

Файловая система перед созданием установщика:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Settings:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код Properties.Settings и MinimizeInTray:

```
   namespace ProcMail.Properties {


    [global::System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CompilerGeneratedAttribute()]
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editors.SettingsDesigner.SettingsSingleFileGenerator", "15.7.0.0")]
    internal sealed partial class Settings : global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase {

        private static Settings defaultInstance = ((Settings)(global::System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase.Synchronized(new Settings())));

        public static Settings Default {
            get {
                return defaultInstance;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.SpecialSettingAttribute(global::System.Configuration.SpecialSetting.ConnectionString)]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf" +
            ";Integrated Security=True")]
        public string Database1ConnectionString {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["Database1ConnectionString"]));
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
        public string Path {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["Path"]));
            }
            set {
                this["Path"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("mail.ru")]
        public string SiteName {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["SiteName"]));
            }
            set {
                this["SiteName"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
        public string MailAdress {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["MailAdress"]));
            }
            set {
                this["MailAdress"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("")]
        public string MailPassword {
            get {
                return ((string)(this["MailPassword"]));
            }
            set {
                this["MailPassword"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("False")]
        public bool DeleteMails {
            get {
                return ((bool)(this["DeleteMails"]));
            }
            set {
                this["DeleteMails"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("10")]
        public int Latency {
            get {
                return ((int)(this["Latency"]));
            }
            set {
                this["Latency"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public global::System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection Filter {
            get {
                return ((global::System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection)(this["Filter"]));
            }
            set {
                this["Filter"] = value;
            }
        }

        [global::System.Configuration.UserScopedSettingAttribute()]
        [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
        public bool MinimizeInTray {
            get {
                return ((bool)(this["MinimizeInTray"]));
            }
            set {
                this["MinimizeInTray"] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код WorkingProgram:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ProcMail
{
    public partial class WorkingProgram : Form
    {
        public WorkingProgram()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            notIconTray.Visible = true;
            this.notIconTray.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseEventHandler(notIconTray_MouseDoubleClick);
            this.Resize += new System.EventHandler(this.WorkingProgram_Resize);


            bwWorking.DoWork += bwWorking_DoWork;
            bwWorking.ProgressChanged += bwWorking_ProgressChanged;
            bwWorking.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            bwWorking.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        }

        private void btnPlay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


                lblWorking.Text = "Программа выполняет свою работу";
            if (cbMinimize.Checked)
            {
                WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
            }

            try
            {
                bwWorking.RunWorkerAsync();

            }
            catch { }


        }

        private void SetBalloonTip()
        {
            this.Click += new EventHandler(WorkingProgram_Click);
        }

        private void WorkingProgram_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void bwWorking_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {


                while (!bwWorking.CancellationPending)
                {
                    if (bwWorking.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }
                MainProgram.RunProgram();
                if(MainProgram.notification == true)
                {
                    notIconTray.ShowBalloonTip(30, "Уведомление", "Письмо было отклонено так как содержало потенциально вредоносные файлы.", ToolTipIcon.Warning);
                    MainProgram.notification = false;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(MainProgram.latency * 1000);

                }

        }

        private void bwWorking_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }





        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Environment.Exit(1);
        }

        private void WorkingProgram_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btnStop_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblWorking.Text = "Программа остановлена, но не сломлена";
            bwWorking.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void WorkingProgram_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
            {
                this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
                notIconTray.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void notIconTray_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            notIconTray.Visible = false;
            this.ShowInTaskbar = true;

            WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }

        private void cbMinimize_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.MinimizeInTray = cbMinimize.Checked;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }

        private void WorkingProgram_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cbMinimize.Checked = Properties.Settings.Default.MinimizeInTray;
        }
    }
}
```

Как можно исправить данную ситуацию?

Comment: Надо смотреть, что у вас происходит в коде классе `ProcMail.Properties.Settings`, в методе `get_MinimizeInTray`.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос.

Comment: Меня терзают смутные сомнения, что вы привели не полный код.

Comment: Полный код Properties.Settings добавлен

Comment: Похоже на то, что файл настроек не может быть создан, поэтому настройки не считываются. Попробуйте запускать от имени Администратора. И на всякий случай, приведите в вопросе код класса `ProcMail.WorkingProgram`.

Comment: Запуск от имени администратора не помог. Я еще думал что с привязкой баз данных могут быть проблемы, но в силу того что приложение определяет верный логин и пароль,  этот вариант исключен

Comment: Вы говорите, что ошибки происходят при каждом действии. Что это за действия? Есть ли ошибки в действиях, не связанные с чтением\записью в настройки?

Comment: Ошибка появляется при нажатии кнопок Запуск программы и Настройки, судя по описанию ошибки программа имеет проблемы с переходами из одного окна в другое

Comment: Что значит проблемы перехода из одного окна в другой? Мне кажется, ошибка связана с файлом настроек.

Comment: Установите для MinimizeInTray значение по умолчанию

Comment: При установке значения MinimizeInTray ошибка не пропала, но в тексте ошибки больше не присутствует упоминание MinimizeInTray. Также теперь ошибка выскакивает только при нажатии кнопки Настройки

Comment: Самое интересное, что данные проблемы пропали как только я вместо установки программы опубликовал ее у себя на компьютере через publish

Comment: Я не вижу, что у вас в коде соответствует нажатию кнопки "Настройки". Установите начальные значения для всех нестроковых параметров в настройках, иначе первое обращение к ним в отсутствии пользователького файла конфига закономерно будет падать с NRE. На компьтере со студией этот конфиг, видимо, уже создан.